# combine Details view and Create View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Good day! I'm still in the process of familiarizing MVC 4 and I have this project in which I have a ParkingLotController which it suppose to have 1 Create view which is an application form and 1 combined Create and Details view where I can View the datas from the application  form and add datas by the use of the create function.
(Edited)
Sorry I forgot mention that I haven't done it yet. what i'm asking is, is it possible to do it? how can i implement the idea? thanks!

Comment: Great. But what is your question?

Comment: Sorry I forgot mention that I haven't done it yet. what i'm asking is, is it possible to do it? how can i implement the idea? thanks!

Comment: Of course. You need to start doing some research. For the combined view, you use a view model containing 2 properties, one for the collection (say) `List<ParkingLot> ParkingLotList` and one for creating a new objects  (say) `ParkingLot NewParkingLot`. But if you want a combined list and create view, what is the point of a separate create view?

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned the first create view is an application form for a parking space it is composed of the owner and the car's details(Brand/Model, Or Number, Cr Number, Plate Number.)  once the application is created it will be posted on the details view wherein if the application is approved additional datas will be added such as Sticker number, slot number on the application data .